# why this program doesn't give the expected output?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

```
int main()
{
    char *c = "abc";
    *c = 'd';
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run this program in C then the program crashes..I want to know what is the error here?

Comment: `c` is pointing to a string literal which is in turn unmodifiable yet you're trying to change one of the characters.

Comment: In case you're wondering, `char c[4] = "abc";` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the string literal `abc` is actually stored in a read-only area of the process and you are not supposed to modify it. The operating system has marked the corresponding pages as read-only and you get a runtime exception for an attempt to write there.

Whenever you assign a string literal to a `char` pointer, always qualify it as `const` to make the compiler warn you about such problems:

```
const char *c = "abc";
*c = 'd'; // the compiler will complain
```

If you really want to modify a string literal (although not directly itself, but its copy), I would suggest using `strdup`:

```
char *c = strdup("abc");
*c = 'd'; // c is a copy of the literal and is stored on the heap
...
free(c);
```

Comment: a "`char *` pointer" would be a `char **`.

Answer (score 1):

`"abc"` is a string literal.

`*c = 'd'` is an attempt to modify that string literal.

You cannot modify string literals.

Comment: Note that on some platforms, you can modify string literals.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Attempting to modify string literals causes undefined behavior. Even if it doesn't crash on some platform, it can cause other bugs (such as changing a different string as well).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: You can't if you want your program to exhibit defined behaviour.